# Can we please have monospaced font on the app post editor?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, editor

It would be nice to have monospaced font in the editor so it would be easier to line up code, space things out, etc. It's really frustrating with trial and error to determine how to align code. Can we please get a monospaced font on the app for the editor?